# Data structure using c++

Tags: c++

if we are having are having an array of pointer i.e.

```
struct node*ptr[];
```

and if we want to initialize its value of first index (`ptr[0]`) by null then how can we do that?

Comment: This is C, not C++. Your question specifies C++ though and you have tagged it as C++. Are you writing C++ or C?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to initialize `ptr[0]` you must either specify a fixed size for your array (`struct node *ptr[1]` for example) or allocate memory (`struct node *ptr[] = new node *;`

Comment: Does `struct node*ptr[] = new node*` actually compile? I believe that you cannot declare the variable `ptr` to be of type `struct node*[]`, as the type is not fully defined (size unknown)

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: Right… `struct node **ptr = new node *` should be better :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can also do something like this:

```
struct node* ptr [10] = { 0 };
```

which initializes all pointers to null.

Answer (score 2):

`struct node*ptr[];`

does not really declare a valid array, typically you need to specify a size or initialize in such a way that the compiler can determine the size at *compile time*. Also, you don't need the `struct` in C++, it's a throwback to C!

for example, valid options are:

```
node* ptr[10] = { 0 }; // declares an array of 10 pointers all NULL
```

or, you can initialize without the size and the compiler figures it out..

```
node* ptr[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; // 10 node* pointers all NULL
```

Comment: actually i want to create a general tree. which has this structure

Comment: struct node{char name[50]; char designation[50]; struct node*ptr[]; }

Comment: *p; if the tree is empty then p=NULL;

Comment: For such a thing I would seriously consider using `std::vector` of `node*` (or if you can use boost, `ptr_vector`, or store `shared_ptr` in `std::vector`). However I have a feeling that this is homework, if so, you'll need to look at dynamically allocated C-style arrays (using `new`), something like: `node** ptr;` and then to create the array, `ptr = new node*[10];` for example...

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to use a statically sized array, use `std::array`.  If you using an array that can be resized, use `std::vector`:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

struct Node {};
typedef std::vector<Node*> DynamicNodeArray;
typedef std::array<Node*, 10> StaticNodeArray;

int main()
{
    DynamicNodeArray dyn_array(10);     // initialize the array to size 10
    dyn_array[0] = NULL;                // initialize the first element to NULL

    StaticNodeArray static_array;       // declare a statically sized array
    static_array[0] = NULL;             // initialize the first element to NULL
}
```

Comment: @Stephane STL != standard library. Also, `std::array` is not in the STL. (It is in TR1 - but that effects the stdlib NOT the STL.)

Comment: Notice what std:: scoped namespace means: STANDARD. Thus, std::vector **is** part of the standard library, and std::array **is** in the standard library of the upcoming C++0x. And its been years I havent written stdlib, looks like it's been deprecated for years ;-) in c++ we would write #include <cstdlib>; if we needed it from time to time ;-) If you wan't to play with words.

Comment: @Kitsune:  `std::array` is already implemented in any compiler that supports the upcoming C++0x standard (MSVC and GCC among them).  If you happen to have a compiler that doesn't support that yet, you can use `std::tr1::array`, or `boost::array` as they are the same thing.

Comment: @Zac @Stephene The fact that `std::array` is in TR1 or C++0x (not even a standard yet) does not have any bearing on the fact that is is not, and never will be, part of the STL. The STL is a specific library put out by SGI. The c++ standard library was based on the STL but is not the STL. I'd expect c++ programmers to know and respect minor details like what something is called. http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/stl/info note what the wiki says about the last 2 definitions.

Comment: @Kitsune:  You appear to be arguing against something I never said.  Nowhere in my answer, nor in any comment, did I even mention STL.  You are the only one talking about STL here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ptr[0] = NULL;`  (assuming you have declared `ptr` correctly i.e. something like `ptr[10]`) Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

This is based on C

```
  struct node*ptr[];
```

This means ptr can hold address of node, it is a array of node type pointer. just like

```
struct node *start = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

As you know array size is fixed, we have to give array size before it's use, so first of all you have to give array size.

Here `malloc(sizeof(struct node))` will return void type pointer, that by we have to do type casting.